# What happens when there are no more mana tokens of a color in the supply?

Tags: mage-knight

If I am supposed to gain a mana token of a basic color that has run out in the supply, what happens? Am I unable to gain any mana tokens of that color that round, or will I gain imaginary mana tokens?

The base game comes with 12 mana tokens of each basic color. This is just enough for each of the four players to have 3 mana of a single color in their inventory. This leads me to believe that mana tokens are supposed to be infinite. You don't need to physically have the tokens to play your round, only to indicate crystals in between turns. But I can't actually find anything in the rules about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There's no component limit on mana tokens.**

Use some other indicator (dice or other objects) to track your mana tokens for the turn, if needed.

The game comes with enough tokens for players to store their maximum allowance of mana crystals (page 6 of the [rules](http://wizkidsgames.com/wp-content/uploads/mage/MK_walkthrough_ENG_searchable-mar2012.pdf)). However, there's no mention of limits for mana tokens. The game explicitly tells you to gain mana tokens when you've hit your limit of crystals, so it seems unlikely that you wouldn't be allowed to do this just because other players are also holding onto crystals.

Also, based on the mana crystal limit, we expect that the rules writer *will* make limitations explicit.

While it isn't covered explicitly in the rules, other players have said [the same](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/932898/mana-crystals-your-inventory):

> There is no limit to the number of mana tokens you may have, but they go away at the end of the turn whether used or not.